# $L^{2}$ convergence, pointwise convergence

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question about $L^{2}$ convergence, pointwise convergence.

Let $(E,\mathcal{B},m)$ be a measurable space and $\mathcal{D}$ be a dense subset of $L^{2}(E;m)$.

The following assertion is true?

For any $f \in L^{2}(E;m)$, there exists $f_{n} \in \mathcal{D},\,n=1,2,\cdots$ such that $f_{n}\to f$ in $L^{2}(E;m)$ and pointwise on $E$$\cdots(\star)$.

Ex.

Let $f_{n}=f \chi_{\{-n\leq f \leq n\}}$. Then $f_{n}\to f$ in $L^{2}(E;m)$ and pointwise on $E$. But  $f_{n}$ is not always a member of $\mathcal{D}$.

Do you know a example of $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ which satisfy $(\star)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, by the density of $\mathcal{D}$ in $L^2$ exists $f_n\in\mathcal{D}$ s.t. $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$. Pointwise convergence is not guaranteed. But $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$ implies *something* about some subsequence...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will use your explanation as reference.